Is Grendizer U a continuation or a remake of the 80's series?
In the 80's as a kid I watched the original Grendizer series, a spinoff of the classic 70's  Mazinger, one of the first popular mecha animes of all times. Now delightedly I've seen they started airing Grendizer U, which his name for some reason sounds like a sequel to me, but the summaries I've seen sounds more like a remake.
So what is it? Is Grendizer U a remake of the original series, a continuation, a spin-off  or what?
